# how to get request.getParameter for scriplet value

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have set the name of the button as <%=j%>, how do i pass this name to servlet with request.getParameter..

```
    <form action="loop">
    <table>
    <%! List product=new ArrayList(); %>
    <%! List company=new ArrayList(); %>
    <% product=(ArrayList)session.getAttribute("product");
       int j=1;
       int i=0;
       while(i<product.size())
       { %>

       <tr>
           <td>
               Product:<%=product.get(i)%>
          </td>
          <td>
                <button type="submit" name="<%=j%>" value="<%=j%>"/>
                </td>
         <% i++; j++; 
       } %>


            </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: do not use java code in JSP

Comment: Have a look at the HTML that this generates.

Comment: @JavaLearner1, Are you want to get name of submit buttons.

Answer (score -1):

try this,may be help to you.

```
while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()){
        String paramName=(String) paramNames.nextElement();
         String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
         for(int i=0; i<paramValues.length; i++) 
         {
             out.println("<li>" + paramValues[i] + "</li>");
         }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of using `submit`, use `button`

```
<input type="button" name="<%=j%>" value="<%=j%>" onclick='onButtonClick(this.value);'/>

<!-- outside your loop -->
<input type="hidden" id="buttonValue"/>
```

and use the below javascript

```
function onButtonClick(val){
    document.getElementById('buttonValue').value = val;
    document.formId.submit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in 2 way,

1. Enclose this in Form tag (your entire code) and in the action you can call a js method like(getButtonName()).

2.Use JSTL tag and iterate the list. I have given you an example.

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${product}" varStatus="loop">
<li><a onclick="getButtonName(${loop.index})" href="#">Product:${product}</a></li>
```